# moving mean on a circle

Tags: matlab, mean

Is there a way to calculate a moving mean in a way that the values at the beginning and at the end of the array are averaged with the ones at the opposite end?

For example, instead of this result:

```
A=[2 1 2 4 6 1 1];
movmean(A,2)
ans = 2.0 1.5 1.5 3.0 5 3.5 1.0
```

I want to obtain the vector `[1.5 1.5 1.5 3 5 3.5 1.0]`, as the initial array element 2 would be averaged with the ending element 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generalizing to an arbitrary window size `N`, this is how you can add circular behavior to [`movmean`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movmean.html) in the way you want:

```
movmean(A([(end-floor(N./2)+1):end 1:end 1:(ceil(N./2)-1)]), N, 'Endpoints', 'discard')
```

For the given `A` and `N = 2`, you get:

```
ans =

1.5000    1.5000    1.5000    3.0000    5.0000    3.5000    1.0000
```

Answer (score 2):

Convolution offers some nice ways of doing this.  Though, you may need to tweak your input slightly if you are only going to partially average the ends (i.e. the first is averaged with the last in your example, but then the last is not averaged with the first).

```
conv([A(end),A],[0.5 0.5],'valid')

ans =

     1.5000    1.5000    1.5000    3.0000    5.0000    3.5000    1.0000
```

The generalized case here, for a moving average of size `N`, is:

```
conv(A([end-N+2:end, 1:end]),repmat(1/N,1,N),'valid')
```

Comment: I was thinking to do it this way. But the thing that I did not like in this solution is that then the output has different dimensions. Also the conv if instead of 2 values we average on more. Of course I can crop the output, but I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do it

Comment: I see, the output has the correct dimensions for `conv` if you had the `'valid'` flag, but yes, gnovice's solution shows the flags for `movmean` to get the desired result there.

Comment: I updated my answer to show the generalized form for `conv` and took out the `movmean` answer as that is covered better by @gnovice.

Answer (score 2):

For an arbitrary window size `n`, you can use [circular convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_convolution) with an averaging mask defined as `[1/n ... 1/n]` (with `n` entries; in your example `n = 2`):

```
result = cconv(A, repmat(1/n, 1, n), numel(A));
```